# css word wrap that wraps whole word without breaking them?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I need to fit a long text to a width of about 300 pixels. I'm using this `css`:

```
 div {      
      width: 300px;
      color:white;
      word-wrap:break-word;
      }
```

My issue is with the `word-wrap:break-word;`. It's breaking words in the middle of the word. But what I need is to have the words stay as they are, and for the document to be smart enough to break the line when appropriate, and keep the words themselves intact.

Is that possible? I tried every option of `word-wrap` but nothing works. Either the paragraphs are not breaking and the text stays off screen, or the words break and a couple of letters are in one line, while other letters are in the following line.

EDIT: adding my code to form a concrete example. My entire `style` element:

```
<style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 10.0px OpenSansHebrew-Regular}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 10.0px OpenSansHebrew-Regular; min-height: 12.0px}

div {
    width: 300px;
    color:white;
    font-size:10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

pre {white-space:break;}

</style>
```

Then in the `body` element:

```
<body bgcolor="#1fa0e2">
<p class="p1">
<div>
<bdo dir="rtl">
<pre>
    דירת 3 חדרים ברחוב ארתור רובינשטיין בתל אביב הוצעה באחרונה למכירה ב–2.5 מיליון שקל, ובסופו של דבר נמכרה ב–2.195 מיליון בלבד - פער של 12% בין המחיר המבוקש למחיר המכירה. בירושלים, דירת 4 חדרים ברחוב צביה יצחק הוצעה למכירה ב–1.6 מיליון שקל ונמכרה ב–40% פחות - 950 אלף שקל בלבד.

</pre>
</div>
</bdo>
<span class="Apple-converted-space"> </span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you were typesetting something like poetry, you could use the `<pre>` element, but otherwise, I think you want to be looking at the `white-space` property.

Comment: Insufficient information. Comments now say that the content is within `pre`, which is crucial. Please edit the question itself to contain enough information to actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @JukkaK.Korpela, I added code that should allow for doing that.

Comment: It’s still not clear what you want. The `pre` element means preformatted text. Why do you use it when you don’t want preformatted text (i.e., spacing and line breaks shown exactly as in HTML source)? A normal `p` element would be adequate for displaying a paragraph of text. Text will then be wrapped at whitespace.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, we're talking about the Terms of Service of an IOS app. It has about 50 paragraphs and I don't want to format them using objective-c because that's a ton of garbage work. I need them to fit an iPhone screen of 320 pixels. What's the best way of doing it?

Comment: @Eddy, then you should describe the format of the data and the requirements on rendering. It sounds like a different question. Maybe `div` with `white-space: pre-wrap` is the best option *if* you don’t want to convert the data into well marked-up HTML, but this depends on the exact requirements. And if you now have empty lines indicating logical paragraph boundaries, as I suspect, it should be rather straightforward to convert them to `<p>` tags. This might be all you need (in addition to `dir=rtl` on an enclosing element).

Comment: pre {white-space: pre-wrap;} did it. Thanks @JukkaK.Korpela. If you write it as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Normally the text will break between words.

If that doesn't happen, then

1. either the container is too wide
2. the container is explicitly set to not break on spaces at all. For instance if it is a `<pre>` element, or has the css `white-space:pre;` or `white-space:nowrap;`.
3. the text contains non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) instead of normal spaces.

Solution: use

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

It will make the element behave like a `pre` element, except it also wraps when the line is too long. See also:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol. My text is indeed in a '<pre>' element. Is there a solution? I pretty much have to have it inside '<pre>' because it's very long and full of formatting.

Comment: I added it but it's still breaking the words.

Comment: You should add that to the `pre` element, not to the div. By the way, it helps if you [include a minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in you question and/or in a jsiddle. That way it's easier to pinpoint the exact problem and to show the solution. Now, I'm just guessing what you did wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol. I edited the question and added a minimal example. Thanks for your help.

Comment: to me, this was the issue `(&nbsp;)`

Comment: your #1 helped me; I needed `width: 100%` (to set its width to something so the element knows when the text is overflowing)

Answer (score 39):

I was messing about with this. People didn't mention setting the word-break style too. The default word-break rules must wrap the word at the end of the container space, but doesn't keep the word intact.

So the solution to your problem in CSS would be:

```
pre{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: keep-all; /*this stops the word breaking*/
}
```

Edit:
I was messing with this further and because I'm using bootstrap, their styling seems to mess with pre tag a lot. Use the !important keyword to override their styling.

Comment: Keep-all was the extra line needed to keep words whole. +1

Comment: I'm using East-Asian characters and I have to use ```word-break: keep-all``` to prevent wrapping so thank you! E.g. Stan 스탠 スタン

Answer (score 5):

You can wrap the word with a `<span>` tag and add either `white-space: nowrap` or `display: inline-block`.

Comment: white-space:pre-wrap + word-break:keep-all doesn't work with span + display:block, but with inline-block it's ok. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

**Note::** Make sure your data doesn't read like..
`word&nbsp;word&nbsp;word` or browsers other than chrome think its one word

Sounds crazy but a bug in our companys mobile app was doing this and till I checked our API data I thought the internet had broken :p