# Is it possible using just CSS to stop words breaking onto new line?

Tags: html, css

We have a list of names which are being split between two lines, the issue is that the names should not be split mid name.

I know I can do it using JS by adding extra DOM or by adding a `&nbsp;` (which i can't do on this occasion) but is there a way to achieve this using just CSS?

This...

```
Persons Name, Persons Name, Persons Name, Persons Name, Persons 
Name and Persons Name
```

Should be this...

```
Persons Name, Persons Name, Persons Name, Persons Name, 
Persons Name and Persons Name
```

Apologies in advance if forgot something simple here, it been a long day!

Comment: `&nbsp;` is used to achieve it. How do You want CSS to know that 2 words are names and shouldn't be splitted?

Comment: css cannot handle this, you will need html markup (but not an option for you) or javascript to handle this on the fly.

Comment: I've seen people using the HTML and CSS <span style="white-space:nowrap"></span>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [css word wrap that wraps whole word without breaking them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406112/css-word-wrap-that-wraps-whole-word-without-breaking-them)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I was trying to achieve it the simplest way without any additional markup. The reason for this is the text is added through a CMS using a single input field which strips HTML.

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to use `&nbsp` (non breaking space) between words You don't want to split. In example below, no matter how do You resize the browser's window, `John Smith` will not be splitted.

```html
John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith, John&nbsp;Smith
```

Onother option to use mostly only CSS is to use a style `white-space: nowrap` but You need to wrap every full name inside an HTML tags with class e.g.:

```css
.dontbreak {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>,  <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>, <span class="dontbreak">John Smith</span>,
```

Comment: OP mentions that they can't use `&nbsp` in the question

Comment: Oopss, question was edited. Originally in place of `&nbsp;` there was just a space ;)

Comment: Yeah, I could tell there was code for the `&nbsp` there, so I wrapped code tags around it.

Comment: So this doesn't get down voted, I would remove this answer as it doesn't satisfy the conditions that the OP asked for.

Comment: Some other user answer the same solution like me. I'm not afraid of downvoting. If an author doesn't like the solution...He/She can comment and/or not use it.

Comment: And I posted the same comment to that other user. I'm just watching out for your rep :)

Comment: @zolv, you updated your answer at the same time as I was entering mine.  You got there first, so I've now deleted mine.

Comment: Egh, You didn't need to delete Your answer. It could be useful for somebody else. If it doesn't fully fit author, maybe it brings some clue(?)