# How to make a header containing spans and non-breaking spaces wrap entire words

Tags: html, css, reactjs, line-breaks

I'm doing a React project, with a title styled as such. I want entire words to wrap to the next line:

```
 <h1 id="home-title">
        <span style={{ color: "#0A8399" }}>Effective Altruists</span>
    &nbsp;at&nbsp;
        <span style={{ color: "#E83C31" }}>McGill</span>
 </h1>
```

With no extra styling on `home-title`, the title escapes the viewport as such:

[image]

I've tried many CSS properties on the title, given [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406112/css-word-wrap-that-wraps-whole-word-without-breaking-them) question, and none have made the entire "McGill" wrap to the next line. The best I've got is

```
#home-title {
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

which gives me this:

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not wrapping `&nbsp;at&nbsp;` in it's own span?

Comment: It's also unclear what the final effect should be

Comment: @Paulie_D I want the effect to be that there's no overflow and line breaks take entire words to the next line. Wrapping `&nbsp;at&nbsp;` in its own span did not change anything.

Comment: You mean like this? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/zYKRJPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and the `span`s stopped breaking words when wrapping.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
      <h1 id="home-title">
        <span style={{ color: "#0A8399" }}>Effective Altruists</span>
        &nbsp;at&nbsp;
        <br/>
        <span style={{ color: "#E83C31" }}>McGill</span>
      </h1>
```

Comment: I want the system to work dynamically. On wider screens, there does not need to be a line break

Comment: you should have  mentioned it clearly otherwise there would be no confusion